Set branch for scheduled runs, retain ability to select branch for manual runs
How can I control which branch a scheduled GitHub Actions job runs on by default, while retaining the ability to manually run the same job on a branch of my choice?
I currently have the following:
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

The worflow_dispatch trigger allows for manual runs, selecting a specific branch:

This answer suggests using ref: some-branch in actions/checkout to control what branch the scheduled job is run on. But this effectively prevents being able to select the branch for manual runs.
Is there a solution for setting the branch for the scheduled run, but still retain the ability to choose the branch for manual runs?

You could use a ternary expression like
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    ref: >-
      ${{ github.event_name == 'schedule' && 'some-branch' || github.ref_name }}

That would use some-branch for scheduled runs, and whatever was selected for manual runs.
